# Hiding a <div> tag using wicket & eclipse

Tags: java, html, wicket

I've tried to hide a  tag in wicket, I've managed to accomplish that only in the case that follows:

```
HTML
...
<div wicket:id="div_id">This is what hides</div>


JAVA
final WebMarkupContainer wmc = new WebMarkupContainer("div_id");

Method
public onSubmit(){
      wmc.setVisible(false);
}
```

This manages to get the div hidden, but my div tag has another wicket components inside, and so I can't seem to get this working, error pops saying inner components are not defined in the component "div_id".

Any idea how to get this working?

Thanks guys!!

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of the stack trace and of the real code? It should be running fine if other components are added to the `div` and are present in the HTML.

Comment: Does it work if you do not hide your "div_id" wmc?

Comment: It works if inside the <div wicket:id="div_id"> i DO NOT put another wicket components such as a table with I'm populating via a dataview, this is what i am trying to hide. It works if inside the div tag are just plain html elements, not wicket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a very wild guess, since I don't know how you add the inner components and what exactly fails, but if you add or modify them in onBeforeRender() and you're using Wicket 1.4.x, you'll need to override WebmarkupContainer.callOnBeforeRenderIfNotVisible() to return true...

For Wicket 1.5 this code should be moved to onConfigure()

Comment: Inner components are just a table filled with a data view next to a paging navigator, I'm relatively new to wicket and I'm developing a mid-complex app so thats why i am having this issues thanks for your support

Comment: @JavT We still need to see how and where you construct the inner components and the Exception along with the code that throws it to be able to help.

Comment: Will upload later on today! have to recreate the error since I'm trying not to use that action by now

Answer (score 3):

If you have other components inside that div, you have to add your other components to the markup container you have for the div instead of adding them to your page. What wicket is looking for is a match between the hierarchy on the Java and HTML part.

Comment: Thank you, this pointed out the key idea that I was failing to grasp. Now my project is working as I intended. :)